# Связь объектов в PHP ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Всем добрый день, у меня такой вопрос: допустим

```
class ClassA{

protected $b;

function Constructor($ClassB) {
        $this->b =  $ClassB;
    }

function GetRes($param){
       return $this->b->GetRes($param);
}

}

$a = new ClassA( new ClassB );
echo $a->GetRes();
```

Пример исключительно для отображения сути, в классе `Б` реализован метод `GetRes`, при этом у класса `Б` может быть много потомков с разной реализацией `GetRes`.

Сам вопрос - пусть `GetRes` возвращает массив с набором значений, необходимых классу `А`, как сделать так, чтобы для программиста, пишущего потомок для класса `Б`, при написании `GetRes`, было очевидно, как параметры нужно вернуть?

Большое спасибо, извините если вопрос покажется лаймерским.

Comment: об этом речь?

    function GetRes($param){
        return $this->b->GetRes($param); // must be an array
    }

Comment: Да, как установить протокол, какие ключи должны быть в массиве?

Comment: Только $b не массив, а объект

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант1:
Перед функцией пишем PHPDoc

`/**
 * @param mixed $param
 * @return array(int $key1=> mixed $ret1,int $key2=> string $ret2)
 */`

Вариант2:
Обзываем функцию, чтобы сомнений не осталось:

```
function getArrayOfIntResourceId(){
}
```

Вариант3:

```
class A{
function GetRes($param){

       $b = $this->b->GetRes($param);
       if(!B::correctFormat($b)){
           print 'Формат неправильный, нужен такой.....';   
           return null;
       }   
       return $b;
}

}
```

Comment: Хотелось узнать, как это по-настоящему делается, спасибо!

Comment: По-настоящему пишется PHPDoc и ОТДЕЛЬНО пишется нормальная документация с примерами кода.